# javascript process hang in setImmediate call

Tags: javascript, freeze, backtrace

I have an application which uses setImmediate to yield the expensive sync operation. It sometimes hangs in setImmediate call, and hence console log (" await is over") doesnt come.

```
async function computeHeavyOp() {
     const largeVal = 10000;
     for (let i = 0; i < largeVal; i++) { 
        if ( i % 50 === 0) {
           await new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));
           console.log(" await is over");
        }
     }
}
```

above is simplified version of the application, it registers many callbacks for the events, etc. I am not able to get the minimal version where I can simulate the hang.

How do we debug an hanged JS process. I attached lldb to the pid, it shows as below looks like JS thread is just looping continuously but seems it doesnt resolve the setImmediate promise . Please suggest how can this be debugged. probably some callbacks are added in micro task queue and never getting chance to resolve the macro task setImmeidate. Is there a way to point to JS call stack which could be culprit.. Are there techniques to print the micro tasks queue that are pending and know the JS callbacks that got initiated from my application

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007ff8162b934e libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001036e8361 libuv.1.dylib`uv__io_poll + 871
    frame #2: 0x00000001036d8dca libuv.1.dylib`uv_run + 359
    frame #3: 0x0000000101268ef0 node`node::SpinEventLoop(node::Environment*) + 301
    frame #4: 0x0000000101379f87 node`node::NodeMainInstance::Run(int*, node::Environment*) + 97
    frame #5: 0x0000000101379bb2 node`node::NodeMainInstance::Run(node::EnvSerializeInfo const*) + 130
```

When I print open handles using [wtfnode](https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode) before issuing setImmediate, I just get socket handle which is opened for connecting to database  .

```
- File descriptors: (note: stdio always exists)
  - fd 2 (tty) (stdio)
  - fd 1 (tty) (stdio)
  - fd 0 (tty)
- Sockets:
  - 127.0.0.1:51544 -> 127.0.0.1:2452
```

Comment: I see once the application stops using sinon.useFakeTimers setImmediate starts working as usual. I think this is application bug not the module using setImmediate.

Answer (score 0):

An explicit call to setImmediate resolved the issue irrespective of applications using fakeTimers like

```
 await new Promise((resolve) => Timers.setImmediate(resolve));
```